# How to show '-' in place of null values in a grid panel

Tags: extjs

How to show '-' in place of null values in a grid panel
    code here-

```
var store = Ext.getStore('someStore');
store.each(function (rec) {
    if(rec.get('comment')=="") {
        //what code i will write here to edit that cell with '-'
    }

});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try adding a column renderer to your grid.

```
{ 
  text: 'Comments', 
  dataIndex: 'comment', 
  renderer: function(value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView) {
    if (record.get('comment') == "") {
      return "-";
    } else {
      return record.get('comment');
    }
  }
}
```

Check out the [Column renderer in the ExtJS API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) for more details.

Comment: why not use value instead of record.get('comment')?

Comment: Agreed, that is the better solution. I was just using the OP's example code.